# how can get microsoft iis administration API from remote

Tags: api, iis

we install the microsoft iis administration API from here:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/
```

after instrallation, we access the endpoint from the:

```
https://localhost:55539/
```

but i want access thats endpoint in that address:

```
https://server_ip:55539/
```

how can i do that? tnx :X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open 55539 port in firewall configurations.